# How to load css files, javascript files and images in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

My Application structure is

application

assets

```
  -css
  -images
  -js
```

System

Comment: What you have tried for it??

Comment: i am new to this ,i placed index file in view and have link as assets/images/logo.png but the image is not showing

Answer (score 0):

1- Load url helper in controller's constructor,

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

2- then use base url function to load Js, CSS files in view

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/style.css">
```

P.S: you have to put Js, CSS files in root folders. (Default)

Comment: it is not displaying,my applications is [link] http://localhost/colorsjob/index.php/news/ ,and image is not showing ,when click on the image going to next tab to view it it is showing  [link] http://localhost/colorsjob/index.php/news/localhost/colorsjob/images/logo.png and 404 error

Comment: <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/logo.png')?>" />

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/test.css')?>"/>

//Image
<?php echo img('assets/images/test.jpg')?>
//OR
<img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/test.jpg')?>" />

//Javascript
<script src='assets/javascript/yourscript.js'></script>
```

Comment: it is not displaying i am new to this shall i rewrite url for this

Comment: @GowriSankar `<?php echo base_url();?>` print your base url like this and tell me..

Comment: localhost/colorsjob/

Comment: assets folder is at your root or in application ??

Comment: assets folder is at root folder

Comment: thats why your files are not included because base url return the path to application folder, move assets into application and then try..

Comment: still not displaying